# Atom: How do you toggle bookmarks in an editor?

Tags: atom-editor, bookmarks

How do you toggle bookmarks in the file you are editing? I see you can view all bookmarks, but it wouldn't make sense to view something that can't be set.

[image: ctrl-shift-p bookmark in atom editor]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is CTRL+ALT+F2.

https://atom.io/packages/bookmarks

Strange that it doesn't appear in the command pallet when you search for `bookmark`.

Answer (score 0):

Under Ubuntu its cmd+shift+F2.